TextField inside a ModalBottomSheet performance issues
I have some text fields that I wish to present inside a ModalBottomSheet that I open using showModalBottomSheet.
When running on the iPhone simulator everything works fine. But when running on the device when clicking the button to open the ModalBottomSheet there are performance issues.
Clicking the button hangs for 2-3 seconds before opening the modal sheet and without animation. After releasing the modal and opening again it works as expected - just the first time has this performance hit.
I stripped everything from the code in the modal and noticed that this happens if there is a TextField on the modal. So I tried the most simplified code:
await showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (context) => TextField()
);

This simple code also causes the performance issues I have described above. And if I set autofocus to open the keyboard things get even worse (generally clicking the field to open the keyboard also hands for 1-2 seconds).
I tried running this code with await and without it - same results.
What am I doing wrong here?

void _openModalSheet() async{
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return Form(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }

I created this basic function to open a modal bottom sheet and it works fine on device as well as on simulator.

Copied and pasted your code and same result as I have

Then it could be an device issue , have you tried on multiple devices ?

What could possibly be the iPhone device fault that would cause it just for the first time? And certainly if it happens in one device even if it wouldn't happen on another device that's a huge problem for Flutter. Luckly I'm at the very start of writing my app so I can switch to a different platform now.
